# Get an hex value from console in C

Tags: c, console

I am working on C language. I would like to get an hexadecimal value from console. For example

```
argv[1] = "0xABCFFABC"
```

and I would like to store the value in an array of unsigned char, so at the end I would like to get something like this:

```
unsigned char hex[4] = {0xAB, 0xCF, 0xFA, 0xBC}
```

Then I process the info and I need to do the inverse process: Go from and hex value `{0xFF, 0xAB, 0x01, 0x0A}` to a a string of `"0xFFAB010A"` ??? and print the final value on console.

Comment: Give it a try and show us some code.  Hint: scanf or strtol.

Comment: `if (sscanf(buf, "%2hhX%2hhX%2hhX%2hhX", &byte1, &byte2,...) == 4) {`

Answer (score 0):

For `argv[1]` to `hex[4]`, you can use chux' approach above with `argv[1]+2` as `buf` and `hex[0]` as `byte1` etc.

Going from `hex[4]` to a string and printing that can be done as follows:

```
    char string[2+4*2+1];
    sprintf(string, "0x%02X%02X%02X%02X", hex[0], hex[1], hex[2], hex[3]);
    printf("%s\n", string);
```